# Best practice for property validation from XSD

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I can generate C# model classes from XSD using xsd.exe, but if I add validation attributes to the model properties, next time I generate classes I will lose changes.

What is the best practise to add validation only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to represent all of your validation constraints within XML Schema (XSD), then you will benefit from all constraints being

- defined in a single place,
- expressed according to a clearly defined standard, and
- communicated independent of C#, Java, PhP, Python, Ruby, or any other
  implementation language.

The best practice to attain these benefits is to use purely an XML schema such as XSD to represent all validation constraints.

When developers hit the wall regarding what can be expressed in an XML schema such as XSD 1.0, they typically go in one of several directions:

1. Use assertions that are available in XSD 1.1
2. Migrate to another XML schema such as Schematron or RelaxNG.
3. Replace or augment XSD validation with another validation layer
   based in an implementation language of their choice.  By separating
   this additional validation from the auto-generated validation, both
   automatic and custom validations can co-exist peacefully.

Answer (score 0):

Generating the classes is a method used to increase your productivity when trying to code against an XSD using .net. As you have found it is not a bi-directional tool. I think you have to continue to maintain the code and the XSD seperately - however you might consider inverting your workflow - generate the XSD schema from your classes.

The XSD.EXE tool documentation says "If you specify a runtime assembly file (.exe or .dll extension), Xsd.exe generates schemas for one or more types in that assembly. You can use the /type option to specify the types for which to generate schemas." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)